# C# WPF Virtualizing ListView Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, virtualization

I have the following WPF and C# excerpt in a Visual Studio 2010 application. This code is being caught in the exception when I run my application and saying the content is "{DisconnectedItem}". To me that would mean that my 'loadDesc' function is being called for objects (Checkboxes) that are not currently inside view of the ListView. Why is this? Any help is appreciated.

C# and WPF Code Below:

```
private void loadDesc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string num = (string)(((sender as TextBlock).Parent as StackPanel).Children[0] as CheckBox).Content;

        if (num == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (num.Equals("Tamper"))
        {
            (sender as TextBlock).Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(num);

            dc.ext247[x - 1].desc = ZoneDescriptionsVM.getInstance().zoneDesc[x - 1].description.Trim();
            dc.onOff247[x - 1].desc = ZoneDescriptionsVM.getInstance().zoneDesc[x - 1].description.Trim();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((((sender as TextBlock).Parent as StackPanel).Children[0] as CheckBox).Content.ToString());
    }
}

<ListView KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" BorderThickness="0" Width="260" MaxHeight="400" Margin="10" Name="zonesOnOffStack" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding visible}" IsChecked="{Binding enabled}" Content="{Binding name}" />
                <TextBlock Padding="5,-1,0,0" Loaded="loadDesc" Text="{Binding desc, StringFormat={}({0})}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Whatever you're doing here, you should be doing it at the ViewModel level instead of  in code behind.

Comment: What does the error message (and stack trace) say? Do `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());` instead.

Comment: @HighCore: Can you please explain how that might be done? At the moment I am loading descriptions (text) from one ViewModel into this view shown here (linked to a different ViewModel). I am doing this with making the ViewModel I need access to globally use the singleton pattern so I can simply call .getInstance() in other ViewModel's.

Comment: I don't have hte computer in front of me where the error was happening. It only happens on Windows XP Classic Theme. If on Windows 7 or XP with the Colored Start menu theme there is no error whatsoever. But I did try ex.ToString() and as I recall it said something like 'failure to cast unnamed object to string'. Thus I printed out what should have been string content and found out it was a Disconnected Item

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old, so maybe not that helpful, but I wanted to note a few things.

1. In VS2017 I setup something similar and was unable to reproduce, but I assume this is verbatim code you pasted
2. Mainly, DisconnectedItem seems to be the key, and that is a binding expression issue. I'm curious if the version of xaml you were using didn't like your stringformat not being in single quotes.

Proof that disconnected item is a binding thing:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpressionBase.cs,71f3b982041c21ce

Hope that helps :)